# How can I code the same file from 2 different devices?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a PC and laptop, the main code file is on my PC, but whenever I'm at university I have to use my laptop. Before I go to my laptop I always have to copy the code from my pc and send it to my alt on discord, so I can then copy + paste it and put it in VSCode. Is there any easier methods I can use, where it auto updates whenever you save edits on the file etc. Thanks

Comment: You can create a code repository on GitHub and push and pull code from it instead of the copy pasting it every single time

Comment: In your case, the world of Git will help you. Already heard something about it? So powerful and amazing! And precisely developed to work with several people on a project, or on different end devices. Needs some training time. But there are thousands of good documentation/tutorials out there.